# How can I connect pentaho to SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Service without using Mondrian schema using Driver org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, pentaho, ssas-2008-r2

How can I connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Service without using Mondrian schema using Driver `org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver`?

I can connect with SSAS and getting data using preview option at Spoon >> Transformation
I am following [this article](http://blog.datamensional.com/2012/03/using-xmla-in-pentaho-reporting/).

Successfully done these two steps

1. Set up MS OLAP XMLA Server as SOAP Web Service
2. Connecting Microsoft OLAP to Pentaho Data Integration (KETTLE)

Now trying third step

1. Using Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) to report from Microsoft OLAP

But I can't see column names under `Data Sets > Pentaho Data Integration > MS OLAP`